# Add signature to stored procedure by certificate after alter

Tags: sql-server, certificate, code-signing

I have a stored procedure signed with a certificate. After changing it with `ALTER`, it seems to lose the signature. I have to rerun `ADD SIGNATURE TO` to get it back.

Is there some way to prevent this from happening? Otherwise I have to remember to rerun the `ADD SIGNATURE` script anytime I make changes to the procedure.

Comment: That's the whole point of signing. The signature verifies that the stored procedure *hasn't* been modified since it was signed, and that only people with access to the certificate were able to modify it. If you don't want that assurance, don't use a signature. If you *do*, you have to resign it. If you don't have access to the certificate, you'll have to ask whoever has signing authority to do it for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN documentation states that the signature is dropped when the module is changed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/add-signature-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Naturally, when something is changed, its signature also changes. Otherwise, signatures would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is by design. You must re-sign the SP **every** time you change it.

Otherwise anyone with permission to `ALTER` the SP, but does not have access to the Cert, could change the definition and use the implied permissions of the Certificate for tasks they should be able to perform. That would be a major security flaw.